# Questions regarding Apple's in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I can't find the answer on the following questions in Apple's documentation, so perhaps someone around here can tell me.

My questions are the following:

- When someone buys an in-app purchase, in how much time am I able to see this transaction on iTunes Connect? Immediately? After a day? After a week?
- Is a customer able to recall a transaction and if so, on what grounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will see the transaction the next day of the transaction.
- A customer is able to recall a transaction to Apple, or to you, if his purchase does not suit him, or if the in-app functionnality have not been enabled correctly.